# R numeric to raw

Tags: r

I am able to convert integers to raw like these:

```
pack_i8 <- function(byte) {
  as.raw(strtoi(strsplit(gsub("(.{2})", "\\1 ", as.character(format(as.hexmode(byte), width = 1))), " ")[[1]], 16L))
}

pack_i16 <- function(i16) {
  as.raw(strtoi(strsplit(gsub("(.{2})", "\\1 ", as.character(format(as.hexmode(i16), width = 2))), " ")[[1]], 16L))
}

pack_i32 <- function(i32) {
  as.raw(strtoi(strsplit(gsub("(.{2})", "\\1 ", as.character(format(as.hexmode(i32), width = 4))), " ")[[1]], 16L))
}
```

I am looking the way to convert numeric type to raw:

```
pack_double <- function(dub) {
 ???
}
```

Simple as.raw(dub) gives:

```
[1] 00
```

as.hexmode(dub) does not accept numeric arguments.

Thank you in advance for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.

Just simple:

```
writeBin(1234567890.1234567, raw(), size = 8, endian = "big")
```

do the thing.